# Zstd decompression error - Unknown frame descriptor

Tags: compression, zstd

I'm trying to decompress a .zst file the following way :

```
public byte[] decompress() {
byte[] compressedBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(PATH_TO_ZST));
final long size = Zstd.decompressedSize(compressedBytes);
return Zstd.decompress(compressedBytes, (int)size);
}
```

and I'm running into this :

com.github.luben.zstd.ZstdException: Unknown frame descriptor [java] com.github.luben.zstd.ZstdDecompressCtx.decompressByteArray(ZstdDecompressCtx.java:157) [java] com.github.luben.zstd.ZstdDecompressCtx.decompress(ZstdDecompressCtx.java:214) [java]

Has anyone faced something similar? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That error means zstd doesn't recognize the first 4 bytes of the frame. This can be because either:

1. The data is not in zstd format,
2. There is excess data at the end of the zstd frame.

You'll also want to check the output of `Zstd.decompressedSize()` for `0`, which means the frame is corrupted, or the size wasn't present in the frame header. See the [documentation](https://github.com/luben/zstd-jni/blob/f2716d1366034887f5e1156aad8e33555bf51df3/src/main/java/com/github/luben/zstd/Zstd.java#L579-L612).

Comment: This does not help. i am also facing this error. i did compression using zstd and then i also checked decompressionSize which returns original size from the header which gave the right number. then i tried to decompress and that is when i get the error stating unknown frame descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

```
public byte[] decompress() {
     byte[] compressedBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(PATH_TO_ZST));
     final long size = Zstd.decompressedSize(compressedBytes);
     byte[] deCompressedBytes = new byte[size];
     Zstd.decompress(deCompressedBytes,compressedBytes);
     return deCompressedBytes;
}
```